# Node.js object is not a function - module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a module I created for a node.js app.  The app also uses socket.io and I want to pass the socket.io object into the auction object when I create it.

This works when I do it outside of Node, but inside, I get the error 'object is not a function' -  my guess is it has to do with the module.exports, but I'm sure what it would be.

Any suggestions would be awesome - thank you!

auction.js

```
var Auction = function(socket) {
    this.data      = [];
    this.timer     = null;
    this.socket    = socket;
}

Auction.prototype = {

    add: function(auction) {
        this.data.push(auction);
    }
}


module.exports.Auction = Auction;
```

server.js:

```
var  Auction          = require('./lib/auction');

var auctions = new Auction(socket);
```

> Error: TypeError: object is not a function
>       at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are exporting an object with 1 property `Auction`

When you required the module, you imported an object which looks like

```
{
  Auction: function(){...}// Auction function
}
```

So either export just the function:

```
module.exports = Auction;
```

or reference the property when you require the module:

```
var  Auction = require('./lib/auction').Auction;
```

By default, module.exports is an empty object : `{}`

You can replace `exports` with a function.  This will export just that function.

Or you can export many functions, variables, objects, by assigning them to `exports`.  This is what you have done in your question: assigned the `function Auction` to the property `Auction` of `exports`.

Comment: For me it only works if i `require('./lib/auction').Auction();` with parentheses, any idea why?

Comment: @Tim, In your case, `require('./lib/auction').Auction` returns a function and you have to call the function to execute it by adding the parenthesis.