# Module is an empty object even after overriding module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, module, export

Here is some class in class.js:

```
function Class(value1, value2) {
  this.value1 = value1;
}

Class.prototype = {
  value1: "default_value",
  method: function(argument) {
    this.value2 = argument + 100;
  }
};

module.exports = exports = Class;
```

and here is a file in which I want to use this class:

```
var Class = require('../classes/class.js');
// (...)
var o = new Class(1,22);
```

What I get is an error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

And indeed, `Class` is `{}`. I hoped this will help: [Node.js object is not a function - module.exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893592/node-js-object-is-not-a-function-module-exports), but I did everything like they said. What's wrong in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module.exports = Class;
```

Should be all you need.

Note: your code works for me, though, so perhaps you are not requiring the right class.js

Comment: I tried `module.exports = Class;`, the path is ok...
//edit
Lol, nope, path isn't ok:D. I required test by itself, instead of requiring tested class:). Thanks!